# Add multiple markers in google map gives "Cannot create property 'clickable' on string '1'"

Tags: javascript, java, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I get a string from a servlet in my javascript which is actually an arraylist. I use gson to make the list into json and send response to js. I use `var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)`. The `data` contains location coordinates.

`data` contains something like this: ["12.1456","73.12453","12.786945","75.13451","12.4724,"78.12545"]

I store the latitudes in `latArray` and longitudes in `lngArray` like this:

```
for(i=0;i < data.length;i++)     
{                     
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        latArray = data[i];
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        lngArray = data[i];
    }
}
```

Adding the values in the `latArray` and `lngArray` in marker code like this:

```
function initMap() {
      var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: {lat: bla.blahh, lng: blaa.blaahh},
        zoom: 15
      });
     for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
      {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          //position: {lat:latArray[i],lng:latArray[i+1]},
          position: new google.maps.Marker(latArray[i],lngArray[i+1]),
          map: map,
          title:"This is the place."
        });  
      }
    }
```

But I get this error: `js?callback=initMap:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'clickable' on string '1'`

I dont know for sure if it's saying I have error in line 59. Here's what is in line 59 of the `initMap()`

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: {lat: bla.blahh, lng: blaa.blaahh},
        zoom: 15
      });
```

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip are you saying this isn't minimal, readable? can't you understand what i've asked?

Comment: @geocodezip. i honestly dont understand what is wrong with the question. people are not even viewing my question

Comment: Your question is certainly not complete.  Until you added sample data there was no way to reproduce the issue.  Now it just would require a bunch of work and `center: {lat: bla.blahh, lng: blaa.blaahh},` is obviously not the real code.  A StackOverflow "code snippet" which is runnable and produces the error would be helpful.

Comment: @geocodezip. should i add the location coordinates

Comment: @geocodezip. im getting the string from a servlet. so i cant make the code  runnable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos in your code.

[Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/b3hg4b1x/)

1. This doesn't make any sense (and is what is generating the error reported):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.Marker(latArray[i],lngArray[i+1]),
  map: map,
  title: "This is the place."
});
```

the `position` property of a [`google.maps.MarkerOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions) object should be a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) object not a `google.maps.Marker` object.

2. This doesn't make sense:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    latArray = data[i];
  } else {
    lngArray = data[i];
  }
}
```

If latArray and lngArray are arrays, push the data on to them or use `latArray[some_index] = data[i]`.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/b3hg4b1x/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var data = ["12.1456", "73.12453", "12.786945", "75.13451", "12.4724", "78.12545"];

var latArray = [];
var lngArray = [];

function initMap() {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      // was latArray = data[i];
      latArray.push(data[i]);
    } else {
      // was lngArray = data[i];
      lngArray.push(data[i]);
    }
  }

  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    // was {lat: bla.blahh, lng: blaa.blaahh}
    center: {
      lat: 42,
      lng: -72
    },
    zoom: 15
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // was data.length
  for (i = 0; i < latArray.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      // was new google.maps.Marker(latArray[i],lngArray[i+1]),
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[i], lngArray[i]),
      map: map,
      title: "This is the place."
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try using:** `LatLng()` method

```
for(i=0;i < data.length;i++)
{
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      //position: {lat:latArray[i],lng:latArray[i+1]},
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[i],lngArray[i+1]),
      map: map,
      title:"This is the place."
   });  
}
```

Comment: is array `data` is defined?

Comment: yeah. i even saw its values in `console.log`

Comment: im getting it the first time i run. the next time it's not showing that error

Comment: see related post regarding google marker on stack overflow.
link is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3059044/5954935)